# Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open 'db.json…/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)

Tags: reactjs

`When I try deploy api json-server created by me to vercel, I cann't use api by methods: patch,       post, delete,.... I only use method get. Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open 'db.json' at Object.openSync (node:fs:600:3) at writeFileSync (node:fs:2221:35) at FileSync.write     (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/lowdb@1.0.0/node_modules/lowdb/adapters/FileSync.js:53:14) at db.write (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/lowdb@1.0.0/node_modules/lowdb/lib/main.js:37:21) at /var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/json-server@0.17.0/node_modules/json-  server/lib/server/router/write.js:5:8 at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/express@4.18.1/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) at next   (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/express@4.18.1/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13) at create (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/json-server@0.17.0/node_modules/json- server/lib/server/router/plural.js:246:5) at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/express@4.18.1/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) at next    (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/express@4.18.1/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)`

hope, who's that can help me . thank you.